# Inserting node in XML using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have the below XML:

```
create table #temp(cid int,xml_data xml)
insert into cid
values(1001,
     '<Main>
        <name>''John doe''</name>
        <age>15</age>
    </Main>')
```

I want to add an additional node to this XML based on a simple parametric condition:

desired output:

```
<Main>
    <name>John doe</name>
    <type>Q</type>
    <age>15</age>
</Main>
```

code:

```
select case when @type = 'Q' then
    UPDATE #temp
    SET Main.modify('insert <type = 'Q'> into 
        (/Main)')
    GO
```

I am getting syntax error. Any help!

**UPDATE:**

I implemented the suggested solution in my code and I'm getting below error. Missing out something silly!

```
 UPDATE #temp
         SET xml_data = 
            case
                when @type = 'G' 
                then xml_data.modify('insert <type>G</type> into (/Main)[1]');
                when @type = 'Q' 
                then xml_data.modify('insert <type>Q</type> into (/Main)[1]'); end
```

I am getting 'Incorrect use of the XML data type method 'modify'. A non-mutator method is expected in this context.' error

Comment: The syntax error is pretty obvious: Your `insert <type = 'Q'>` trys to insert a *not well-formed* node... Btw: Do you really want to wrap "John doe" in quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for any complicated hassel. Just insert the node you want as you want it:

```sql
UPDATE #temp SET xml_data.modify('insert <type>Q</type> into (/Main)[1]');
```

Using `as first`, `as last` or `before / after` allows you to specify the node's position. The following will place the new node directly after `<name>`:

```sql
UPDATE #temp SET xml_data.modify('insert <type>Q</type> after (/Main/name)[1]');
```

### UPDATE Your question about an update-statement

Your statement has several flaws:

> ```
> UPDATE #temp
>      SET xml_data = 
>         case
>             when @type = 'G' 
>             then xml_data.modify('insert <type>G</type> into (/Main)[1]');
>             when @type = 'Q' 
>             then xml_data.modify('insert <type>Q</type> into (/Main)[1]'); 
>          end
> ```

You cannot use the syntax `SET xmlColumn = xmlColumn.modify()`. You have to use `SET xmlColumn.modify()`, Furthermore the semicolons are breaking this anyway.

To be honest, I think this is to complicated, try this:

```sql
DECLARE @type VARCHAR(1)='Q'
UPDATE #temp SET xml_data.modify('insert <type>{sql:variable("@type")}</type> into (/Main)[1]');
```

This will create a new node `<type>content</type>`, with a content taken out ot the variable `@type`.

Comment: this approach is looking simple. But I am missing out something silly that I'm getting an error. Updating the question with my new error and code trial

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve this by breaking the update into two statements:

```
create table #temp(cid int,xml_data xml)
insert into #temp
values(1001,
     '<Main>
        <name>''John doe''</name>
        <age>15</age>
    </Main>')


    UPDATE #temp
    SET xml_data.modify('insert <type /> into (/Main)[1]')
    GO

    declare @variable xml = 'q'
    UPDATE #temp
    set xml_data.modify('insert sql:variable("@variable") as last into (/Main/type)[1]')
    GO

    select * from #temp
```

[image]

Comment: No need for this approach. You can insert the new node in one go easily. See my answer...