# Incorrect use of the XML data type method 'modify'. A non-mutator method is expected in this context

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to update XML data column in a table based on case. Below is my code:

```
UPDATE #temp
SET xml_data = CASE
                  WHEN @type = 'G' 
                     THEN xml_data.modify('insert <type>G</type> after (/Main/name)[1]');
                  WHEN @type = 'Q' 
                     THEN xml_data.modify('insert <type>Q</type> after (/Main/name)[1]'); 
               END
```

I am getting an error:

> Incorrect use of the XML data type method 'modify'. A non-mutator method is expected in this context.

Desired output:

- When `@type = 'Q'`, insert type node as `Q`
- When  `@type = 'G'`, insert type node as `G`

XML structure:

```
<Main>
    <name>John doe</name>
    <type>Q</type>
    <age>15</age>
</Main>
```

Any help ?!

**UPDATE:**

My edited query:

```
UPDATE #temp
SET xml_data.modify('insert <Type>{sql:variable("@var")}</Type> after (/Main/name)[1]')
```

This query is adding the type to the end of the XML. Output:

```
<Main>
    <name>John doe</name>
    <age>15</age>
</Main>
<Type>Q</Type>
```

Comment: your *edited query* (UPDATE-section) will never create the result you state at the end... `Type` != `type` (xml is strictly case-sensitive)...

Comment: Good catch Shnugo. But while copy pasting my output I edited it,. Now I will edit my question and paste the actual output that I am getting

Comment: Rick, I'm pretty sure, that there's something else... Might be you are checking the wrong XML, might be this `<Type>Q</Type>` was modified persistantly in one of your former attempts and you just think this was introduced with this statement. `after (/Main/name)[1])` will place this new node at the specified place...

Comment: Rick, in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50936745/5089204) you are inserting `into (/Main)[1]`, I'm pretty sure you left this unchanged with `after` in the beginning ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax is `SET [xml_column].modify`, no use of the assignment. Instead of using `CASE`, fold the variable into the update using the special `sql:variable` function:

```sql
UPDATE #temp 
SET xml_data.modify('insert <type>{sql:variable("@type")}</type> after (/Main/name)[1]');
```

Comment: Good answer (+1 from my side)! Rick has placed this question as a follow-up in a comment [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50943267/5089204) and I've given exactly the same advise ;-D

Comment: Thanks man! My parameter was messing up everything but I fixed it :D Thanks @Shnugo :)

Comment: I am facing an issue related to this update and I am opening a new question mentioning my scenario. If you can help me resolve, it will be great!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE #temp
   SET xml_data = 'insert <type>' + @type + '</type> into (/Main)[1]'
```

Sample:

```
DECLARE @myXML XML = 
N'<Main>
    <name>John doe</name>    
    <age>15</age>
  </Main>'  ;       

SET @myXML.modify('insert <type>Q</type> into (/Main)[1]') ;  

SELECT @myXML;
```

Comment: How does it help? I'd say that's plain wrong, but might be I don't get the gist...